# Posso colocar uma TD de uma TABLE com características de botão através de classes Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-4

Eu costumava utilizar buttons dentro de TD quando criava tabelas dinâmicas em que cada linha (TR) tem um botão.

Mas eu comecei a ver que o pessoal ao invés de colocar botões dentro dos TD, colocavam uma TAG "a" e atribuía classes (bootstrap) de botões para essas TAG "a".

Como:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary">
```

Isso já transforma uma TAG "a" em um botão.

**Agora eu gostaria de saber se ao invés de eu fazer isso abaixo:**

```js
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, emp) {
  //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 


  empresas += '<tr id="' + emp.codigo + '">';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.imagem + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.usuario + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.EMPRESA_ORIGEM + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.departamento + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn btn-md btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-alterar-empresas">ALTERAR</a></td>';
  empresas += '</tr>';

});
```

**Eu talvez possa fazer isso.**

```js
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, emp) {
  //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 


  empresas += '<tr id="' + emp.codigo + '">';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.imagem + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.usuario + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.EMPRESA_ORIGEM + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td>' + emp.departamento + '</td>';
  empresas += '<td href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-alterar-empresas" class="btn btn-md btn-success" style="text-align: center;"></td>';
  empresas += '</tr>';

});
```

Isso funcionaria ?

Essas questões de atribuir classes de botões em TAGS que não são botões é uma coisa válida ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara são muitos detalhes, mas de cara já te falo que isso é completamente errado, pois vc não pode colocar um `href` em uma `TD`, e isso não teria semântica alguma ou mesmo seria acessível

```
<td href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-alterar-empresas" class="btn btn-md btn-success" style="text-align: center;"></td>
```

A opção de customizar uma tab `<a>` como um `<button>` tb não faz muito sentido, a não ser pelo fato de no `button` vc não conseguir colocar um link `href`, pois ele é usado para `submit` ou para uma ação via JS. Além disso, o `button` pode fazer um `submit` e ser acessado com a tecla *backspace* (espaço) por exemplo, e tem uma semântica diferente que um A que na verdade é um *hiperlink*.

Vc pode até customizar um `<a>` como um `<buttom>`, mas o propósito deles é bem diferente assim como a semântica já dito acima.

Como vc pode ver aqui os atributos globais de um `button` são totalmente diferente do `A` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

> O Elemento HTML  representa um botão clicável.

Elemento `A` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

> O elemento HTML  (ou o Elemento Ancora HTML define uma hiperligação (hyperlink), o destino de uma hiperligação, ou ambos.

Comment: Estou perguntando isso pq estou tendo dificuldades para fazer que um botão ocupe toda a altura e largura de um td, e assim o seu background ocupar toda a td. Até consegui chegar perto, mas não consigo fazer perfeitamente e em dispositivos menores, como smartphones, fica péssimo.

Comment: Quando trabalhamos com elementos dinâmicos, o que menos queremos é utilizar muitos elementos filhos para um pai. Pq, eu acho, que não fica fácil manipulá-los depois. Por isso não gosto de colocar um "tr" que tem um "td" dentro e que tem "button" dentro e por fim um "a". Ou seja, 4 elementos onde talvez poderíamos usar apenas um (o "td").

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson "gostar" ou "ser fácil assim" não eh desculpa para fazer errado... O no caso vc tem que entender o proposito do elemento, normalmente vc não vai ter um A dentro do Btn, vc tem que ver qual se encaixa melhor para o que vc quer fazer, e mesmo eu não gostando o menos problemático eh o A com o button dentro, e não o contrario, mas pra mim isso eh gambiarra... Mas vamos ver as vezes aparece alguém com outra solução, e o btn vc pode colocar com width de 100% para ocupar toda td

Comment: A questão do width 100% não funciona por completo. E fica ainda pior quando utilizamos em dispositivos menores que 768 px. Já tentei utilizar o w-100 e o h-100 do bootstrap mas mesmo assim não ficou 100%. Mas concordo com vc que essas gambiarras não são benéficas em relação as "boas práticas".